# How to still view Cell color of selected row in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Lets say a JTable has rows with various cell colors like this.

[image]

If the first 2 rows are highlighted, it looks like the following and now the colors seen for the first two rows are lost.

[image]

Is it possible to make the highlighted rows more transparent so that the underlying colors are still visible? Something similar to what Excel does. Notice the same 2 rows are highlighted and yet the colors are still visible while its still obvious the rows are highlighted/selected.

[image]

Here is a modified sample I pulled from the Java2 page and modified it for the above example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

class EvenOddRenderer implements TableCellRenderer 
{

  public static final DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
  {
      Component renderer = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
      isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
      Color foreground = Color.red, background = Color.WHITE;
      
      if (column == 1 && row == 0) 
      {
          background = Color.GREEN;
      }
      else if (column == 1 && row == 1) 
      {
          background = Color.CYAN;
      }
      else if (column == 1 && row == 2) 
      {
          background = Color.ORANGE;
      }
      else if (column == 2)
      {
          background = Color.YELLOW;
      }

      if (isSelected)
          background = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

    renderer.setForeground(foreground);
    renderer.setBackground(background);
    return renderer;
  }
}
public class CellColorTransparency {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    final Object rowData[][] = { 
        { "1", "one",  "I" },
        { "2", "two",  "II" },
        { "3", "three", "III" }};
    final String columnNames[] = { "#", "English", "Roman" };

    final JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new EvenOddRenderer());    
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Color Test Table");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually easier than expected.

Simply use the darker() call within the Renderer.

```
      if (isSelected)
      background = background.darker();//Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
```